# How to refresh gradle task's targets

Tags: java, gradle, build.xml, gradle-task

I have a project, in which I automate build using gradle. I made a task's target in **build.xml** file:

```
<project basedir="." default="build" name="GGP_Base">
  <target name="SimpleServerGameDolar">
    <java classname="banan314.utilities.SimpleGameDolar" failonerror="true" fork="yes">
        <classpath refid="GGP_Base.classpath"/>
    </java>
  </target>
</project>
```

It worked, I ran it using `gradle simpleGameDolar`.
But then I renamed the java class `SimpleGameDolar` to `SimpleServerGameDolar` and changed the classname in the target. And when I run it in the same way, I get the error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class banan314.utilities.SimpleGameDolar
>   :simpleGameDolar FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What can I do to refresh gradle so that it knows that I changed tasks?

I tried `gradle clean`, `gradle build` and reopen IntelliJ but neither helped.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you're still using an Ant `build.xml` in a Gradle build?

Comment: I forked from GGP_Base project and adapted its way of build. That project was founded in 2010. It's my first use of Gradle at all. I don't know if `build.xml` is obsolete or not. I don't know how to upgrade that to another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, thanks to the comment of @Oliver, I realized that `build.xml` has completely nothing to do with my gradle build. `build.xml` is in Ant build. After I changed the right file - `build.gradle` - it works as I expected. I was even able to delete `build.xml`.